# Should DTOs in a composite DTO reference each other by primary key or by object reference?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, dto, data-transfer-objects

There is a recommendation that [transfer objects should not contain object references to other transfer objects](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=102319#). Instead, they should use the primary keys of the other transfer objects as foreign key fields.

**Simple example with Order and Customer as entities**

Clearly, an OrderListDTO containing a list of orders without customer details will contain foreign keys to the details of the ordering customers.

A composite DTO OrderWithCustomerDTO will have object references to an OrderDTO and to a CustomerDTO. But should the embedded OrderDTO itself have a object reference to its CustomerDTO in this case? Or should it use the primary key of the ordering customer?

**Indication for object references**

One advantage is that the client can directly use the transfer object, e.g. as presentation model. I tend to accept this approach for transfer objects that are always completely self-contained, e.g. a composite DTO with related DTOs or a complete tree. The client can rely on the self-containment. The client doesn’t need to post-process the transfer object at all.

**Indication of primary keys as foreign keys**

The advantage is that internal and external references are treated the same way. I tend to require this approach for transfer objects that might contain external references, e.g. a subtree with external childIds. The client must iterate over the complete list to resolve the external childIds.

**More complex example with a tree or subtree**

The transfer object in question now is a tree or subtree. Technically, it's a list of nodes.

Is it ok if the nodes in the transfer object reference each other by object references like the NodeTOWithObjectReferences below?

```
public class NodeTOWithObjectReferences implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private NodeTOWithObjectReferences parent;
    private List<NodeTOWithObjectReferences> children;
}
```

Or must the transfer object replace EVERY object reference by a foreign key field like the NodesTOWithForeignKeys below?

```
public class NodesTOWithForeignKeys implements Serializable {
    private List<NodeDetail> children;
}

public class NodeDetail implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private long parentId;
    private List<Long> childIds;
}
```

(I opted for transfer objects to encapsulate the domain model from the clients and to provide client specific data views.)

Answer (score 3):

> As a general recommendation, transfer
>   objects should not contain object
>   references to other objects. Instead,
>   they should use the primary keys of
>   the other objects as foreign key
>   fields.

Could you attach a link to the source of this recommendation? It's at least not obvious to me.

In my current project I use transfer objects which contain object references. It's convenient and I haven't met any problems with this approach yet.

Comment: In [Advanced J2EE Platform Development: Applying Integration Tier Patterns](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=102319#) it says: "Transfer Objects must never contain or reference Composite Transfer Objects; instead, whenever possible, Transfer Objects should reference other Transfer Objects using their primary keys." I feel that the anomaly of my example is the self-reference of the tree. A composite TO has object references to its building TOs. And a list TO with only orders has foreign keys to customers.  But how for a list TO with orders accompanied by the ordering customers?